# faraday connection failed on rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i get connection failed, which shows this error:

```
rake aborted!

Faraday::ConnectionFailed: execution expired
```

How can i get this to not explode my rake task and just either try again or skip to the next row?

Heres my rake task

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
namespace :webtask do
  task populate: :environment do
    Event.all.each do |row|
      tweventname = I18n.transliterate(row.eventname)
      url = url here
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      doc.css('.table__row--event').each do |tablerow|
        table = tablerow.css('.table__cell__body--location').css('h4').text
        next unless table == row.eventvenuename
          tablerow.css('.table__cell__body--availability').each do |button|
            buttonurl = button.css('a')[0]['href']
            if buttonurl.include? '/checkout/external'
              else
            row.update(url: buttonurl)
          end
          end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a standard rescue block is what you need.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
namespace :webtask do
  task populate: :environment do
     Event.all.each do |row|
      begin #Tells rescue where to jump 
      tweventname = I18n.transliterate(row.eventname)
      url = url here
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      doc.css('.table__row--event').each do |tablerow|
        table = tablerow.css('.table__cell__body--location').css('h4').text
        next unless table == row.eventvenuename
          tablerow.css('.table__cell__body--availability').each do |button|
            buttonurl = button.css('a')[0]['href']
            if buttonurl.include? '/checkout/external'
              else
            row.update(url: buttonurl)
          end
          end
      end
    end
   rescue Faraday::ConnectionFailed
     next
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey there, Thanks for the answer but i got an error on this, Which sucks!